# Controlling which edges are visible in a network diagram in igraph in r

Tags: r, colors, igraph, vertices, edges

I have a the following diagram created in `igraph`

```
set.seed(1410)
df<-data.frame(
"site.x"=c(rep("a",4),rep("b",4),rep("c",4),rep("d",4)),
"site.y"=c(rep(c("e","f","g","h"),4)),
"bond.strength"=sample(1:100,16, replace=TRUE))

library(igraph)
df<-graph.data.frame(df)
V(df)$names <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
layOUT<-data.frame(x=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4)),y=c(4:1,4:1))
E(df)[ bond.strength < 101 ]$color <- "red"
E(df)[ bond.strength < 67 ]$color <- "yellow"
E(df)[ bond.strength < 34 ]$color <- "green"
V(df)$color <- "white"
l<-as.matrix(layOUT)
plot(df,layout=l,vertex.size=10,vertex.label=V(df)$names,
edge.arrow.size=0.01,vertex.label.color = "black")
```

[image]

I want to show all the vertices/nodes but only edges where bond.strength > 34 (i.e. only the red and yellow edges). I can control this by setting bond.strength < 34 to white but it is not pretty when done on my actual data set as the white edges "cut through" the other edges i.e.

[image]

Are there other way of simply controlling which edges are visible whilst showing all the vertices? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wonder what happens if you set the color of the lines to be transparent, something like:

```
E(df)[ bond.strength < 34 ]$color <- "#FF000000"
```

I cooked up that color number with:

```
 hsv(1,1,1,alpha=0)
```

Alternatively, you could go in and omit them from your edgelist.

Comment: This is actually not perfect, because some devices do not support transparency. A better solution is to set the line type to `0`, which means no line at all: `E(df)[ bond.strength < 34 ]$lty <- 0`.

Comment: pretty cool! transparency was the trick I need to make nodes silently disappear. size = 0, shape = "none" and a lot of other settings simply didn't work. thanks